# e.preventDefault() почему ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мой код

```
$('body').on('click','.filter_button a.filter', function(){
ShowCatalogFilter('.filter_button a.filter');
})
function ShowCatalogFilter(e){
e.preventDefault();  
e.stopPropagation();
  var req = $(e).parents('.catalog-form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
     dataType:"html",
     data: req,
    success:function(data){
     location.replace(data.replace(/'/g,""))
       }
     })
   };
```

Ошибка : Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: Эм... Потому что в функцию передаётся не объект события, а текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас получается `e` не ивент а селектор, может так

```
$('.filter_button a.filter').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();  
e.stopPropagation();
ShowCatalogFilter('.filter_button a.filter');
})
function ShowCatalogFilter(selector){

  var req = $(selector).parents('.catalog-form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
     dataType:"html",
     data: req,
    success:function(data){
     location.replace(data.replace(/'/g,""))
       }
     })
   };
```

Comment: зачем делегирование убрали?

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаёте строку, а ожидаете что будет [объект события](https://learn.javascript.ru/obtaining-event-object), у которого Вы можете отменить [реакцию браузера](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) и [распространение события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Можно отменить их в преобработчике, как в ответе [@Arsen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640398/207618), а можно [забайндить](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) на передачу объекта непосредственно в функцию:

```
$('.filter_button a.filter').on('click', ShowCatalogFilter.bind(this, '.filter_button a.filter'));
```

Тогда в функцию попадёт объект события, которое уже можно отменить, прочитать, etc:

```
function ShowCatalogFilter(selector, e){}
```